# Modal is not working in my webserver but works in localhost. Why is that?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using asp.net webforms. I have button in top of the page and when user click the button I want popup a modal window. 
This is the code that I used to implement it. The code works fine on my localhost. But on the production server nothing happens.

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

above references were placed at Masterpage.

Below code is put at aspx page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="uppnlModalDistrict">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalOpen" Width="100%" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Select Location" OnClick="btnModalOpen_Click" />

                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <section>
                                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

     </div>
               </div>
                                    </div>

                                </section>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code behind when I click the btnModalOpen buton.

```
    protected void btnModalOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetModalDistricts(); //Function that populate data in Modal
        uppnlModalDistrict.Update();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal()", false);
    }
```

In aspx

```
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
```

So what is wrong with this code?

This is the console error

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The
message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes
for this error are when the response is modified by calls to
Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is
enabled.

Details: Error parsing near
```

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan Please check the updated answer

Comment: Could be that your webserver is not handling / blocking scripts and then passing an error page back?  Try opening the .js files directly in the browser (or use network tab) to ensure they are loading correctly.    But doesn't look like an issue with the .js files or the modal itself.

Comment: make sure you have referenced `JQuery` and `Popper.js` in you live server app.

Comment: @Sylar, I have just posted an answer for you. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is that you have not emitted the opening and closing script tags for the JavaScript that you have registered at startup, since the last parameter to the method `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is false in button click event handler, when actually it should be true.

So simply use the line below to replace your original line and problem will be solved.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal()", true);
```

The only time you should pass a false as last parameter to `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is when the script you are registering already contains opening and closing script tags as in line below.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop",
                         "<script type='text/javascript'>openModal()</script>", false);
```